# Is there any advantage for Java over C#

Tags: c#, java, c++, programming-languages

This question may sound silly.. but my intention is to understand advantages of **Java over all other programming languages** ??

I guess c# is more or less similar to java.. also c# is derived from c++ which  inturn is derived from C..

So learning which language is more easier or helpful in understanding concepts & developing programs..

Comment: That question makes Java sounds like it is the best. Ignoring that, however, Java is very cross-platform. You can even write Java applications that run on a cell phone. It offers a lot of script-like capabilities like introspection, but is efficient enough with the way it deals with bytecode that it outperforms even the fastest scripting languages like lua. I think those are the most unique qualities that Java has.

Comment: If this is "subjective" and deserves to be closed, then how could "Karthikeyan"s question be written to compare the qualities of the Java and C# such that it is not subjective? Is it possible?

Comment: I fear that you are going to be badly downvoted on this one, as being subjective, argumentative, etc. Which is a pity, as inventing a new language is not easy and (presumably) no one does it without a reason. Which means that in some some way, each language is (/was) better suited to particular tasks than others. For Java, some folks might say cross-platform (but so is c/c++), or cross-platform with GUI (just add Qt to c++), etc My *personal* opinion is that is that every language gets invented to solve a particular problem domain and in v2.0 they decide to add in features from other languages

Comment: `So learning which language is more easier or helpful in understanding concepts & developing programs`

You might find some who will argue for BASIC (whichever dialect), or Pascal, which was also invented as a teaching language.

Are you clear in what you want to know here? Do you want to learn how to code, or how to design software, or think in algorithms, or what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Java is supported on most platforms, whereas C# mostly [runs on other platforms](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) but is not supported by Microsoft.
- There are more external tools (like static code analyzers) for Java than for C#, although it is a matter of time before this goes the other way. When a scientific study is done into VM optimization or error detection, Java is mostly used.
- Since Java and C# are developed by different companies, there are differences in licensing, usage terms and conditions, pricing for support or software, etc.

Update: .NET Core is now also [supported on Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux) and macOS.